# to translate 6 latin sentence sentences to english with a step by step process on how you translated it

Tags: latin-to-english-translation

Can anyone translate these six Latin sentences (from chapters 38-39 of Annales) to English, and follow me through step by step on how you did it?

> Ignis impetu ventorum vectus circum corripuit nec eius vis opprimi potuit.
>
> Domibus non erant munimenta, templis non erant muri.
>
> viae erant et flexae.
>
> Itaque sine impedimentis flammae omnia devastabant.
>
> Flammae iam ubique ardebant antequam homines eas extinsguere temptaverunt.
>
> Propter lacrimas et timores feminarum et propter eos qui huc atque illuc currebant omnia erant in tumultu.

Thank You very very much I really appreciate it. I tried translating it myself and I am able to figure out the translate the words, I just can't put them in the sentence the right way. I also struggle with moods, prep phrases, and finding direct and indirect objects.

Comment: Hi, Phillip! Generally with translation questions we ask that you provide some context to the question, and show a reasonable attempt at translating it yourself. Welcome to the site!

Comment: As @SamK comments, you should show what you have been able to do yourself and ask specific questions. For example, are you in doubt about a specific feature in all those sentences? Currently your question comes across as "please do my homework for me", which I'm sure you didn't intend. I put your question on hold, but it can be reopened if you can elaborate on it. Do ask for help if you are unsure about how to improve the question.

Answer (score 2):

**Step ONE**: Look for the verbs. Here you are lucky; they all end in **t** or **nt.**  “It did something or other...” or “**They** did something ot other...”
**Step TWO**  Look for the conjunctions (or punctuation): These two steps tell you the *shape* of the phrase.

> .I. (xxxxxxxxxxxxx **corripuit**) nec (xxxxxxxxxx **potuit**)
>   ‘(It did this) and  not (...it couldn’t do that)
>   .II.(xxxxxxxx **non erant** xxxxxx) , (xxxx **non erant** xxx)
>   (they weren’t ) , (they weren’t).
>   .III. **Itaque** (xxxxxxxxxxx **devastabant**)
>   Therefore (the xxxx were devastating).

**Step THREE**: Look for the nominatives and accusatives; especially plurals for plural verbs ending ‘nt’, and the nom singular for singular verbs ending ‘t’.
**Step FOUR**; while you’re looking for those, see if you can make sense of the fiddly bits: the adverbs and other descriptive bits added for colour.

> (**Ignis**, the only nom singular noun, **corripuit**) and not (**vis**.........**opprimi potuit**)
>   ((*fiddly bits*: ‘driven by the onslaught of the wind’) nec (and ‘its strength’ was not...))

another example:

> (**Flammae** nominative plural; **ardebant**, plural verb) antequam (**homines**...**temptaverunt**)
>   (**iam ubique**, the flames 'now everywhere' were... ) before (the men...........)